# Regex Search program, how not to duplicate answers during iterate thru text? (Python3)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working on a 'Regex Search' project from the book Automate boring stuff with python. I tried searching for answer, but I failed to find related thread in python.

The task is: *"Write a program that opens all .txt files in a folder and searches for any line that matches a user-supplied regular expression. The results should be printed to the screen."*

I am sending below the part of code that I have problem with:
    import glob, os, re

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\PythonScripts')

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    content = open(file)
    text = content.read()
    print(text)
    for i in text:
        whatToFind = re.compile(r'panda|by|NOUN')
        finded = whatToFind.findall(text)
    print(finded)
```

I would like to find that 3 words: panda|by|NOUN
After iterate thru text, I get output with repeated answers couple times. I get the answer *'by'* two times, but it should be only once. 
For example for text:

> 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN
>   was unaffected by these events.'

I get:

> ['panda', 'NOUN', 'by', 'NOUN', 'by']

I should get only 4 first strings. I tried to fix it but I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are missing the *word boundaries* in your regular expression pattern and `by` from the "nearby" word was also matched:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: whatToFind = re.compile(r'panda|by|NOUN')

In [5]: s = 'The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.'

In [6]: whatToFind.findall(s)  # no word boundaries
Out[6]: ['panda', 'NOUN', 'by', 'NOUN', 'by']

In [7]: whatToFind = re.compile(r'\b(panda|by|NOUN)\b')

In [8]: whatToFind.findall(s)  # word boundaries
Out[8]: ['panda', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'by']
```

---

Note that there is probably a better way to look for words in an English text - using a natural language processing toolkit ([`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/)) and its `word_tokenize()` function:

```
In [9]: from nltk import word_tokenize

In [10]: desired_words = {'panda', 'by', 'NOUN', 'cookie'}

In [11]: set(word_tokenize(s)) & desired_words  # note: "cookie" was not found
Out[11]: {'NOUN', 'by', 'panda'}
```